# Need to sort out by tables name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below

```
termnum       dialnum         carrier         cic            mou 
8007779898    8007779898      LEVEL3          432          86,466 
8886605890    8886605890      LEVEL3          5102         83,302 
8779069811    8779069811      LEVEL3          432          69,955 
8779069811    8779069811      LEVEL3          432          69,955
```

Below is the query I am using to get the above table:

```
select c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic, sum(c.calldur)/60

from tablec c
left join  tablea a
on c.dialnum = a.NUMBER8XX 
group by c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic

union 

select c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic, sum(c.calldur)/60

from tablec c
left join  tableb b
on c.dialnum = b.NUMBER8XX 
group by c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic
```

Termnum and dianlnum are coming from specific table and I am trying to sort out my data according to that. I tried different case statements but no result. 
I am trying to get the data so it looks like below:

```
termnum         dialnum         carrier     cic    mou    table a      table b
8007779898     8007779898        LEVEL3     432    86,466    X  
8886605890     8886605890        LEVEL3     5102   83,302                X
8779069811     8779069811        LEVEL3     432    69,955    X           X
```

Comment: I am using sql server management studio

Comment: you might want to post your schema for better understanding here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to wrap up your aggregation, then using `case` expressions with `exists()` to determine which tables `dialnum` exists in.

```
;with cte as (
  select c.termnum, c.dialnum ,c.carrier ,c.cic ,sum(c.calldur)/60 as mou
  from tablec c
  group by c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic
)
select c.*
  , table_a = case when exists (select 1 from tablea a where a.NUMBER8XX = c.dialnum) then 'x' else '' end
  , table_b = case when exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.NUMBER8XX = c.dialnum) then 'x' else '' end
from cte c
```

---

written without the [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
select c.*
  , table_a = case when exists (select 1 from tablea a where a.NUMBER8XX = c.dialnum) then 'x' else '' end
  , table_b = case when exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.NUMBER8XX = c.dialnum) then 'x' else '' end
  from (
    select c.termnum, c.dialnum ,c.carrier ,c.cic ,sum(c.calldur)/60 as mou
    from tablec c
    group by c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic 
      ) c
```

Comment: WOW!!!! I was not even close to understanding this issue and I think you knocked it out of the park. We know who has the mind reading hat today. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Only if I'm right. I'm not so sure yet. OP may want to full join on all values or something -- or be pulling from a master table and two sub tables... waiting for some comment from OP.

Comment: @SqlZim thank you for your help. The first table is basically a table c and there is no column from table a and table b
To know if the the termnums are coming from one of these table I am joining the table c with table a and table b by termnum but I am not able produce the desired table which I am showing in the below

Comment: @Mr.Jin Please edit your question and include your table schema, example data, attempted query etc.

Comment: @SqlZim I just edited my post with the query. Maybe that can help understand

Comment: @Mr.Jin I have updated my answer, please let me know if that is what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @SqlZim It worked. One question what is with cte? This is first time I have seen.

Comment: @Mr.Jin the `cte` is a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). In this instance it is just used instead of using a derived table (subquery) in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `case` at all.  Just add a static column to the results.

```
select c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic, sum(c.calldur)/60, 'A' as SourceTable

from tablec c
left join  tablea a
on c.dialnum = a.NUMBER8XX 
group by c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic

union 

select c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic, sum(c.calldur)/60,  'B' as SourceTable

from tablec c
left join  tableb b
on c.dialnum = b.NUMBER8XX 
group by c.termnum, c.dialnum, c.carrier, c.cic
```

Comment: I don't want to put table information in one column Sourcetable. I need to show it how I am getting this information by showing the two table columns. So, it'll be easier for my manager to read it.